# Mount and dismount hard drive through a script/software - as Admin

Tags: windows-10, command-line, runas

The answer to this previously asked question is excellent - it works perfectly when I run it *manually*, "As Administrator".

However, I want to be able to Mount my USB-backup drive - just before backing up to it - and then Dismount it immediately on completion of backup (using feature of Acronis True Image that allows a before & after cmd/batch-file to be run) ... so that the drive is NOT visible to any nasty Ransomware that may attack me.

So, my follow-up question is;  How am I able to get a cmd/batch file to run "as Administrator" without my attendance ?

Comment: You may want to have a look here -- https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/76933-run-bat-admin-without-uac-prompt.html

Comment: Suggestion by Anaksunaman (to look at https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/76933-run-bat-admin-without-uac-prompt.html) addresses my question perfectly - Thank you !

Comment: Welcome. Glad to hear it. =)

Comment: A follow-up question, if I may;   The tenforums.com site referred to above contains suggestion to convert the bat/cmd file to .exe ... with referral to F2KO Software's "Bat to Exe Online Converter" (http://www.f2ko.de/en/ob2e.php)    Does anyone know if this is safe to use ?

Comment: I poked at it and It's safe as far as I could tell (take that with a block of salt). ;-) That said, there are some limitations on the free version (supposedly exes are only valid for the PC they are created on - - though I did not test that limit).

Comment: Once again, thank you Anaksunaman - You've been very helpful.

Comment: Not a problem. =)

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer to your question "How am I able to get a cmd/batch file to run "as Administrator" without my attendance?" is that you can do this through the Windows Task Scheduler.

When creating a task in Task Scheduler you can choose the "Run with highest privileges" option to run it as an administrator. These tasks can be run automatically without your intervention.

However, this may not work in your specific use case because it sounds like you want Acronis to trigger the batch file rather than just have a batch file which can run automatically as an administrator. If Acronis is run as an administrator it should inherit the ability to run other things it calls as administrator so that's a possibility but it would depend on Acronis supporting that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by configuring a New task in the Windows Task Scheduler set to run on demand and then call it as outlined below.

(Note: You must create a Brand new task using "New task" not "New BASIC Task" as basic tasks never truly convert to real tasks and are limited.)

1. Create a Folder for your scripts in Task Manager Lets Call it "MyScripts"
2. Under this Folder Create a "New task" with the name "MountUSB"
3. Make sure you specify the task to run as your username and save the
   password
4. Set the task to be run "On demand"
5. Select the newest OS compatibility version available to you on your
   OS.
6. Select the "Run with Highest Privileges" Tick-box.

You can now call this Task from a script or program as follows:

```
schtasks /run /I /TN "\MyScripts\MountUSB"
```

Repeat the above with a task named "UnmountUSB" for your ending script.

Note, if Acronis has trouble running this task (access denied) then change the task to run using your username and password as follows:

```
schtasks  /run /U "YourUserName" /P "YourPassword" /I /TN "\MyScripts\MountUSB"
```